# VS Code regular expression is not working

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am using VSCode to try removing unnecessary white spaces from my code, but it seems that this command is not working. Does anyone know why?

I am using the latest version of VS Code.

[image]

[image]

I have tried searching for other keywords and they all work, except for regular expressions which are not functioning properly.

Comment: Do you have the regex option enabled? The `.*` option in the Find Widget.

Comment: Until now, I have been directly using Ctrl + H to search for ^\s*(?=\r?$)\n and then replace it. How can I enable it?

Comment: If you expect tabs (\t) then you could [ ]{2,} and just replace with a space. Obviously if you don't have tabs and your IDE is purely using space then you have an issue, but I've never found this with VSCode

Comment: I realized that the setting wasn't turned on (Alt + R). It used to automatically open before, but I discovered yesterday that I need to manually enable the regular expression setting (Alt + R).